# How to implement a Collision Resistance Hash Function in Charm Crypto Python?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, charm-crypto

I am trying to implement a collision resistance hash function i.e. [Hash Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhtUq.png) in charm crypto. I have checked the hashModule.py and Hash.py classes and tried the Waters Hashing Scheme also. But I unable to find a collision resistance hash function which maps to ZP*.

Comment: Have you read [ask]?

Comment: What is *p*? You probably mean Zr instead of Zp* in Charm.

Comment: Dear @ArtjomB. Thanks for all your comments. YesI meant Zr, not Zp*. I have solved it using group.hash('string', Zr) function.

Comment: @Aisha Then please post an answer to your own questions if you've solved them. I edited many of your questions in order to increase visibility in case you haven't solved them yourself.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Following is the code to hash in Zr. 
message1 = "message"
msgHash = group.hash(message1,  ZR)

Comment: No, not a comment. You should post a properly formatted answer and accept it afterwards.